Getting type errors and module not found errors on render deployment
I am trying to deploy a MERN App on render.
The build gives this error.
../backend/src/models/hotel.ts(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mongoose' or its corresponding type declarations.
../backend/src/models/user.ts(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mongoose' or its corresponding type declarations.
../backend/src/models/user.ts(2,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bcryptjs' or its corresponding type declarations.
../backend/src/models/user.ts(22,8): error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
../backend/src/models/user.ts(23,9): error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
../backend/src/models/user.ts(23,43): error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

The user.ts file is:
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export type UserType = {
    _id: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
    password:{type:String,required:true},
    firstName:{type:String,required:true},
    lastName:{type:String,required:true}
});

//function to be executed before saving the user to the database
//this is actually a middleware
userSchema.pre("save", async function(next: mongoose.CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError){
    if(this.isModified("password")){
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password,10);
    }
    next();
});

const User = mongoose.model<UserType>("User",userSchema);

export default User;

I have the mongoose and bycryptjs types installed via this command:
npm install --save-dev @types/mongoose @types/bcryptjs
my tsconfig.json file includes:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}


When I hover over this, my VS Code gives me the following
this: mongoose.Document<unknown, {}, mongoose.FlatRecord<{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}>> & mongoose.FlatRecord<{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}> & {
    ...;
}

These are my versions:
  "@types/mongodb": "^3.6.8",
  "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
  "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",

"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"mongodb": "^6.3.0",
"mongoose": "^6.0.12",



This is my build command on render.
cd frontend && npm install && npm run build && cd ../backend && npm run build
But I am still getting this error and I don't know what to do.

It's more a npm installation related error.
In the render.com settings of your project you should have a build command like that:
npm install && npm run build


for my project i have src/ relative path, don't pay attention.
